# How to configure frame footer in metropolis theme

Tags: beamer, footer, beamer-metropolis

I would like to configure the frame footer in the metropolis theme.
For now, I just added the footer with

```
setbeamertemplate{frame footer}{xyz}
```

I would like to change the frame footer's font into:

- Smaller font (also for the page number)
- Another font color (grey) (also for the page number)

Is it also possible to use "author" and "institute" in this frame footer?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme[
 outer/progressbar=frametitle,
 inner/sectionpage=progressbar
]{metropolis}                   

\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\date{\today}
\author{name}
\institute{inst}

\setbeamertemplate{frame footer}{xyz}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{First Section}
\begin{frame}[t]{First Frame}
xxx 1
\end{frame}

\section{Second Section}
\begin{frame}[t]{Second Frame}
xxx 2
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please add a small example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` to play with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame footer}{\insertshortauthor~(\insertshortinstitute)}

\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=gray}

\author{names}
\institute{institute}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What if we wanted to add the title as well?

Comment: @Y_gr `\insertshorttitle`

Comment: I thought so. But I wanted the title to be in the middle between the author's details and the slide's number

Comment: @Y_gr Can you ask a new question including a MWE?